# CTRL + Mouse click is not opening in new tab

Tags: magento

we installed theme to our magento site.....

in that theme, there is a feature, in listings page, there is a pagination.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxA4E.png

once we click on that pages[ CTRL + Mouse click] its opening in new tab.

please scroll down fully last for below links.

[working](http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/index.php/apparel.html)

but after we done lot of code chnages, now this feature is not working.

[not working](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/toys.html?p=2)

is there any way we can find what is the problem.

```
frontend/base/default/template/page/html/pager.html

<?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>

    <?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>
    <div class="pager">
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if($this->getShowAmounts()): ?>
    <p class="amount">
        <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if($this->getShowPerPage()): ?>
    <div class="limiter">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                <?php echo $_limit ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
    <div class="pages">
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('Page:') ?></strong>
        <ol>
        <?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>
            <li>
                <a class="previous<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?> i-previous<?php endif;?>" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>">
                    <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_left.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($this->canShowFirst()): ?>
            <li><a class="first" href="<?php echo $this->getFirstPageUrl() ?>">1</a></li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($this->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
            <li><a class="previous_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousJumpUrl() ?>">...</a></li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php foreach ($this->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
            <?php if ($this->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
                <li class="current"><?php echo $_page ?></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getPageUrl($_page) ?>"><?php echo $_page ?></a></li>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>


        <?php if ($this->canShowNextJump()): ?>
            <li><a class="next_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getNextJumpUrl() ?>">...</a></li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($this->canShowLast()): ?>
          <li><a class="last" href="<?php echo $this->getLastPageUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->getLastPageNum() ?></a></li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if (!$this->isLastPage()): ?>
            <li>
                <a class="next<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?> i-next<?php endif; ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getNextPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>">
                    <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_right.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForNext() ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif;?>
        </ol>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below code in your file

> ?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>

```
<?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>
<div class="pager">
<?php endif ?>

<?php if($this->getShowAmounts()): ?>
<p class="amount">
    <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
        <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if($this->getShowPerPage()): ?>
<div class="limiter">
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
    <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
            <?php echo $_limit ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
<div class="pages">
    <strong><?php echo $this->__('Page:') ?></strong>
    <ol>
    <?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>
        <li>
            <a target="_blank" class="previous<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?> i-previous<?php endif;?>" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>">
                <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_left.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if ($this->canShowFirst()): ?>
        <li><a target="_blank" class="first" href="<?php echo $this->getFirstPageUrl() ?>">1</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if ($this->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
        <li><a target="_blank" class="previous_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousJumpUrl() ?>">...</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php foreach ($this->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
        <?php if ($this->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
            <li class="current"><?php echo $_page ?></li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getPageUrl($_page) ?>"><?php echo $_page ?></a></li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>


    <?php if ($this->canShowNextJump()): ?>
        <li><a target="_blank" class="next_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getNextJumpUrl() ?>">...</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if ($this->canShowLast()): ?>
      <li><a target="_blank" class="last" href="<?php echo $this->getLastPageUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->getLastPageNum() ?></a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if (!$this->isLastPage()): ?>
        <li>
            <a target="_blank" class="next<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?> i-next<?php endif; ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getNextPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>">
                <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_right.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForNext() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif;?>
    </ol>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: file not updated.please enable template path hint and check file path.

Comment: i replaced your code and uploaded, i removed cache now, please check, its not working

Comment: got this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/html/vikas/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/pager.phtml on line 122

Answer (score 0):

just add "target='_blank'" property  in <a> tag

Comment: please check code inquestion  . where i need to add this code.